Flutter button which expands when pressed
I have an ElevatedButton, and I'd like it to response to the user's touch by growing slightly in size, say around 10%
Ideally it would be an animation with a smooth change in size as you press and release the button. A kind of touch feedback, but altering the button size rather than changing colour or using ripple effects.

Please try animated container widget.

One way to achieve this is using a ButtonStyle. You can pass a class implementing MaterialStateProperty<Size?> to minimum size, which will allow you to increase the size when the button is in the pressed state.
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ButtonStyle(minimumSize: MyMinimumSize()),
  child: const Text('Press me'),
),

class MyMinimumSize extends MaterialStateProperty<Size?> {
  @override
  Size? resolve(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
      return const Size(120, 50);
    } else {
      return const Size(90, 40);
    }
  }
}


You can make this using AnimatedContainer, for changing button size you have to wrap your AnimatedContainer with AnimatedSize widget.
Here I create an animation where I exactly make this animation. take a look then implement your logic.
